# How to delete elements from a list using a list of indexes?

Tags: python

If I have the following list of elements:

```
list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

and I have another list that contains the indexes I need to delete from the list above:

```
to_delete = [0,2]
```

How can I delete those elements from `list` using `to_delete`? Using a `for` loop doesn't work since, obviously, when you delete one element from a list the index of each remaining element changes.

What can I do?

Comment: What can you do? What have you tried?

Comment: I think we just had one of these questions a few hours ago.

Comment: if `to_delete` is sorted, you can just remove in reverse order with for loop as you suggested

Comment: @WillMolter: That can require a quadratic amount of element shifting, though.

Comment: @user2357112 well of course but if the list is small who cares?

Comment: @WillMolter: It's a bad habit to get into, and the inputs might not always be small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) together with a conditional list comprehension to generate a new list containing every element of `my_list` that is not in the index location from `to_delete`.

```
my_list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
to_delete = [0,2]

new_list = [val for n, val in enumerate(my_list) if n not in to_delete]

>>> new_list
['two', 'four']
```

Comment: Not sure how this is not upvoted as it is the best approach, bar you should make to_delete a set for large lists

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension filtering :

```
 [ my_list[i] for i in range(len(my_list)) if i not in to_delete ]
```

Comment: You don't want to use that name `list`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye following OP naming.

Comment: It's still a bad idea. If the OP is doing something wrong, fix it, don't just ignore it.