# Delete elements from python array with given index of elements as list

Tags: python

I am beginning to program in python. I want to delete elements from array based on the list of index values that I have. Here is my code

```
x = [12, 45, 55, 6, 34, 37, 656, 78, 8, 99, 9, 4]

del_list = [0, 4, 11]

desired output = [45, 55, 6, 37, 656, 78, 8, 99, 9]
```

Here is what I have done

```
x = [12, 45, 55, 6, 34, 37, 656, 78, 8, 99, 9, 4]

index_list = [0, 4, 11]

for element in index_list:
    del x[element]

print(x)
```

I get this error. **I can figure out that because of deleting elements the list shortens and the index goes out of range**. But i am not sure how to do it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: it is because after deleting 0th and 4th index element total list size is not > 11, that's why it gives `index out of range error`.

Comment: Use `x = [e for i, e in enumerate(x) if i not in index_list]`, well known pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question already has an answer here. [How to delete elements from a list using a list of indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647439/how-to-delete-elements-from-a-list-using-a-list-of-indexes).

BTW this will do for you

```
x = [12, 45, 55, 6, 34, 37, 656, 78, 8, 99, 9, 4]

index_list = [0, 4, 11]

value_list = []
for element in index_list:
    value_list.append(x[element])

for element in value_list:
    x.remove(element)

print(x)
```

Comment: If the question already has an answer, then flag as a duplicate, do not answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use enumerate:

```
x = [12, 45, 55, 6, 34, 37, 656, 78, 8, 99, 9, 4]

index_list = [0, 4, 11]
new_x = []
for index, element in enumerate(x):
    if index not in index_list:
        new_x.append(element)
print(new_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the `del_list` list in descending order and then use the `list.pop()` method to delete specified indexes:

```
for i in sorted(del_list, reverse=True):
    x.pop(i)
```

so that `x` would become:

```
[45, 55, 6, 37, 656, 78, 8, 99, 9]
```